# Token validation failed Visa X-pay

Tags: java, visa-api

I need to tweak an API https://sandbox.api.visa.com/cybersource/payments/flex/v1/keys?apikey={apikey}
I am imitating the official document [X-Pay Token](https://developer.visa.com/pages/working-with-visa-apis/x-pay-token#sample_code_for_api_key__shared_secret_xpaytoken),but it fail with "Token validation failed" error.

```
{
    "responseStatus": {
        "status": 401,
        "code": "9159",
        "severity": "ERROR",
        "message": "Token validation failed",
        "info": ""
    }
}
```

Below is my x-pay-token generation code.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.SignatureException;

public class T {
    private static String resoucePath = "payments/flex/v1/keys";
    private static String queryString = "apikey=6DC0NMXO53QQFE6NFOLE213HXA-pvG6xE-1NtuCd5oOQr-O-s";
    private static String requestBody = "{encryptionType:RsaOaep256}";
    private static String sharedSecret = "gAynzAGf89+V}3{Q4Jx5cp-/R@Y#PEv#1XvxnjQC";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SignatureException {
        System.out.println(T.generateXpaytoken(resoucePath, queryString, requestBody, sharedSecret));
    }

    public static String generateXpaytoken(String resourcePath, String queryString, String requestBody, String sharedSecret) throws SignatureException {
        String timestamp = timeStamp();
        String beforeHash = timestamp + resourcePath + queryString + requestBody;
        String hash = hmacSha256Digest(beforeHash, sharedSecret);
        String token = "xv2:" + timestamp + ":" + hash;
        return token;
    }

    private static String timeStamp() {
        return String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L);
    }

    private static String hmacSha256Digest(String data, String sharedSecret) throws SignatureException {
        return getDigest("HmacSHA256", sharedSecret, data, true);
    }

    private static String getDigest(String algorithm, String sharedSecret, String data, boolean toLower) throws SignatureException {
        try {
            Mac sha256HMAC = Mac.getInstance(algorithm);
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(sharedSecret.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), algorithm);
            sha256HMAC.init(secretKey);
            byte[] hashByte = sha256HMAC.doFinal(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            String hashString = toHex(hashByte);
            return toLower ? hashString.toLowerCase() : hashString;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SignatureException(e);
        }
    }

    private static String toHex(byte[] bytes) {
        BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(1, bytes);
        return String.format("%0" + (bytes.length << 1) + "X", bi);
    }
}
```

somebody can help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL you are using:
https://sandbox.api.visa.com/cybersource/payments/flex/v1/keys?apikey={apikey}
Should be:
https://sandbox.api.visa.com/cybersource/payments/flex/v1/keys?apikey=6DC0NMXO53QQFE6NFOLE213HXA-pvG6xE-1NtuCd5oOQr-O-s

Answer (score 0):

As on Feb 2020, If some one still has issue below points can help resolve issue.

- Please make sure you have generated API Key and Secret for your sandbox project.
- You can get these details in Dashboard -> Project -> Credentials -> Inbound and Authentication Keys -> API Key / Secret.
- Please check the "Status" of the Key which should be Active.
- If your "Credentials" tab does not have details for "Inbound and Authentication Keys" Please make sure to add the respective API then this section automatically appears.
- Visa has "Visa Developer Center PlayGround" [similar to SoapUI/Postman] tool where you can easily test your API's. Unfortunately this is only supported with Windows as on Feb 2020, In future they may release the same for Mac/Linux too.
- You can find this tool in Dashboard -> Project -> Assets -> Bottom of the page.